# integrate youtube video in existing android app using a drop down spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-youtube-api

I am new to Java and Android programming.
I am Creating an app in which I want to integrate youtube video in one of the layouts.

I want to use a drop-down spinner.
and I want to add a new video to every item in the spinner.
I have no idea how to do that.

Please Explain with suitable codes.

Thank you In advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is not Spinner, that is RecyclerView in which you can show your videos like youtube. But u can't integrate whole youtube to ur app. There are some rules to copy any app. But You can make ur own app with your sever. So, go on and use RecyclerView or ListView to show Your Videos List. Thank You.

Comment: I understand that I cant do that with spinner only I need recycler or webview for that. And I don't wanna show the whole youtube either.

I want to use a spinner . and if any item selected then it starts another activity(recyclerview/webview), where any specific youtube video should play.